# Hash error renaming column names in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rename

I am trying to rename some columns in a dataframe.  First issue (which I solved) was that some of the column names contained the string: \xa0

[image]

You will see below where I replace those with regular spaces (and I check before and after).

Then I am simply trying to rename some of the columns, but I am getting this:
[image]

I have used rename before.  Never had this issue.

Also, in my code below, if I add:  axis=1 I get an error saying unexpected keyword 'axis'.  ??
I assume this is because it is choking on the error below so then it finds fault with axis.

What is wrong with my code?

```
col_names = {'Record ID': 'id',
             'CESSATION YEAR': 'cease_date',
             'Reason for ceasing employment': 'separationtype',
             'Gender.     What is your Gender?': 'gender',
             'CurrentAge.     Current Age': 'age',
             'Employment Type.     Employment Type': 'employment_status',
             'Classification. Classification': 'position',
             'LengthofServiceOverall. Overall Length of Service at Institute (in years)': 'institute_service',
             'LengthofServiceCurrent. Length of Service at current workplace (in years)': 'role_service'
             }
print(list(tafe_survey_updated), '\n')
tafe_survey_updated = tafe_survey_updated.columns.str.replace("\\xa0", " ")
print(list(tafe_survey_updated), '\n')

tafe_survey_updated = tafe_survey_updated.rename(col_names)
for col in list(tafe_survey_updated):
    print(col)
print()
```

*IMPORTANT NOTE*  This issue only started after I replaced the \xa0 with spaces. Prior to that the rename ran fine, but it did not update any column names that contained \xa0.

Comment: try `df.columns.str.replace(r'\\xa0', '')` works for me.

Comment: I tried that.  It does fix the \xa0 issue as well, but then I can't rename the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I had to do this:

```
from unicodedata import normalize

new = []
print(list(tafe_survey_updated), '\n')
for col in list(tafe_survey_updated):
    new.append(normalize('NFKC', col))
tafe_survey_updated.columns = new
print(list(tafe_survey_updated))

tafe_survey_updated = tafe_survey_updated.rename(col_names, axis=1)
for col in list(tafe_survey_updated):
    print(col)
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that knowledge of ASCII Characters, but from what I understand you need to

1. replace `\xa0` characters from your columns
2. rename columns that have different amounts of white space.

we can try like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({r'test_\xa0     data_123' : [0,1,3]})
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'\\xa0', '')


col_names  = {'test_        data_123' : 'data'}
#replace white space in new columns.
new_cols = {}
for k,v in col_names.items():
    new_cols[k.replace(' ','')] = v

#do same for current columns. 
cols = []
for i in df.columns.tolist():
    cols.append(i.replace(' ',''))

df.columns = cols
print(df.columns.map(new_cols)
Index(['data'], dtype='object')
```